# Error in Project when table view is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have tried everything to fix the error but it still comes up.
Basically I have a tableview and when I click on a cell, it loads then the app crashes and comes up with the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

I have tried:

1. deleting derived data
2. check all perform with segue identifiers
   to see if I made an error
3. looked through my code multiple times

link to project: http://www.filedropper.com/ticketekapp_1

Comment: I tried downloading the file but turns out I would need to create an account on fileDropper to download the file. Trust me, not a lot of people will have enough time to do that. Consider uploading to a public link on dropbox perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the project I'm getting the error

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier EventTableViewCell

Solution:

In `EventTableViewController` line 62 change the identifier to `MealTableViewCell`.

The identifier of the cell is not necessarily the type of the cell

Answer (score 0):

Well after running your project the error was clear, you need to add this inside `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(EventTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventTableViewCell")
```

The code will now crash with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

On this line:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = event.name
```

Comment: `EventTableViewCell` is designed (and therefore registered) in Interface Builder, the cause of the error is a identifier mismatch.

Comment: Key here is that OP designed the cell inside the storyboard itself, so yeah, your answer is correct.